Upgrading Django from 3.2 LTS to Django 5.04 causes typeerror: requires_system_checks must be a list or tuple
I just upgraded Django from 3.2 LTS to the latest Django 5.0.4 and updated all packages as on a need basis and I get the following trace after I attempt to run the docker-compose to start my api web server :


my-api            |   File "/opt/my-api-core/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
my-api            |     execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
my-api            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line
my-api            |     utility.execute()
my-api            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 436, in execute
my-api            |     self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
my-api            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 275, in fetch_command
my-api            |     klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
my-api            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 49, in load_command_class
my-api            |     return module.Command()
my-api            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django_media_fixtures/management/commands/collectmedia.py", line 35, in __init__
my-api            |     super(Command, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
my-api            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 285, in __init__
my-api            |     raise TypeError("requires_system_checks must be a list or tuple.")
my-api            | TypeError: requires_system_checks must be a list or tuple.



The following is what I've attempted so far:


The django-media-fixtures is what is seen in the trace so I used
https://pypi.org/project/django-media-fixtures-next/  after changing
it from https://pypi.org/project/django-media-fixtures/
Downgraded
Django up until 4.2.11 and right up until 4.1 from the present 5.0.4


However , the error persists. I do not see the need to modify site-packages itself as it doesn't seem the right way to do it. Looking for a solution to get around this. I did see other stack posts but couldn't solve it in my case.
Here are some :
Django 4.1.9 requires_system_checks issue with manage.py - is this a bug or not
how to fix "TypeError: requires_system_checks must be a list or tuple." caused by "py manage.py grpcrunserver" command?

Neither of the two packages you linked are maintained anymore, updating those won't really help. You can fork them if you want as described by the answer below.

@AbdulAzizBarkat That's not a duplicate as the OP is already aware of that question but it doesn't help them solve this particular issue. As you mentioned updating the dependency won't really help.

@Selcuk I was of the thought that the duplicate pretty much explains the problem and what the app developer would need to fix. The fork to me is a really obvious solution, but I guess maybe not to everyone. I'll reopen this then.

Yes, the problem is in django-media-fixtures (and django-media-fixtures-next) which are not being maintained anymore. You can fork the project on Github and use your own fork as a dependency. You will have to change this line:
    requires_system_checks = False

to
    requires_system_checks = []

in your fork.
You can then change the relevant line in your requirements.txt to:
django-media-fixtures @ git+https://github.com/<your username>/django-media-fixtures


Will do as you recommended Selcuk. Thank you.
